# MySql LeftJoin From Three Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to get the  data from the game table and whether all gamers have signed up for an available match(Yes/No)
An available match is one where the date is current or in the future

**Gamers**

```
(PK)Gamer_Id
Gamer_firstName,
Gamer_lastName,
Gamer experience(Y/N)
```

**Game_matches**

```
(PK)FK GamerId,
(PK)FK MatchId,
 Gamer_score
```

**Match**

```
(PK)Match_Id,
gameDate,
ExperiencedGamers_needed,
InExperiencedGamers_needed
```

This is what I've tried, I know it's incomplete.
     Do I need to use a CASE as well?

```
SELECT G.*, COUNT(M.`matchId`)
FROM game_matches GM
LEFT JOIN MATCHES M
ON M.`matchId` = GM.`matchId`
LEFT JOIN Gamers G ON G.`userId` = GM.`userId`
WHERE G.`gameDate` >= DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY G.`userId`
```

Are there any other ways to acheive this other than using the cross join solution from JW?

Comment: what do you want to to get? users that have not signed up on a certain match? can you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: I need to get a yes or no , if all gamers have signed up for all matches available (i.e  today or in the future)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.GamerID,
        a.Name,
        COUNT(*) = COUNT(c.GamerID)
FROM    Gamers a
        CROSS JOIN `Match` b
        LEFT JOIN GameMatches c
            ON  a.GamerID = c.GamerID AND
                b.MatchID = c.MatchID
WHERE   b.gameDate >= CURDATE()
GROUP   BY  a.GamerID,
            a.Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e48be/21)

What the query does is it first gets the cartesian product of all gamers and all the matches starting today. After that, the results will be joined on table `GameMatches` on two columns: `GamerID` and `MatchID`.

If the result of the cartesian product of the tables has no matches on table `GameMatches`, the values of the columns are *NULL*. Thus, it test if `COUNT(*)` which is the total number of records is equal to `COUNT(c.GamerID)` which is only the total number of gamers that have signed up.

Comment: can you give sample records that we can test with?

Comment: why does it return empty? `COUNT()` will definitely return atleast one record.

Comment: and what are you expecting to get?

Comment: see my updated answer. and here's the demo, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e48be/10

Comment: +1.  Note that the derived table b isn't strictly necessary. The table Matches could be referenced, and the predicate on Match.gameDate could be included either in a JOIN predicate (ON clause), or in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Nothing at all, I just wanted to know, if there is another way it can be done, like another join

Answer (score 0):

You are only selecting the games that have matches in the future.  If you want the count of future matches, you need a conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT G.*, sum(case when g.gameDate >= date(now()) then 1 else 0 end) as FutureMatches
FROM game_matches GM
LEFT JOIN MATCHES M
ON M.`matchId` = GM.`matchId`
LEFT JOIN Gamers G ON G.`userId` = GM.`userId`
GROUP BY G.`userId`
```

In practice, you may be able to use `inner join` rather than `left join` because the ids should match between tables (unless you are interested in users that have no matches at all).

Comment: An inner join here would ignore the gamers that have signed up for zero games

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH MATCHES AS
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_MATCHES FROM MATCH WHERE gameDate >= CURR_DATE
)

GM AS
(SELECT G.GAMER_ID, COUNT(*) AS GAMER_MATCHES
GAMERS G, GAME_MATCHES GM
WHERE G.GAMER_ID = GM.GAMER_ID
GROUP BY G.GAMER_ID
)

SELECT GM.GAMER_ID
FROM GM, MATCH
WHERE GAMER_MATCHES = TOTAL_MATCHES
```

Comment: MySql does not support WITH